# Are there 2 ways to wire a ceiling light?

Tags: wiring

I went to replace a (two wire) spring driven timer with a (four wire) digital timer, but found only two wires (and a bare ground) in the switch box.  I'm guessing the cable from the circuit breaker runs to the box at the light (as opposed to the switch box), then a side cable runs down to the switch box.  Regardless, I replaced it with another spring driven.

What factors determine whether the cable from the breaker gets run to the switch box or to the light box?

Comment: Jimmy Fix-it’s answer is correct.  While we don’t do product recommendations on this site, I’ll nudge you towards Intermatic model ST01.  It’s a battery powered timer that will work in your situation.  (Intermatic states the button style battery will last 3 years between changes).  With ST01 hook up the blue, black, and green (capping the red).  If your location is really old and there’s no ground available this timer will work, however you must use a plastic plate and plastic plate screws (although it looks like that phrase has been deleted from the printed instructions.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are speaking of the neutral (grounded) conductor, until relatively recently it was not common for it to be routed through a switch box.

Switches (and timed switches) control associated loads by connecting/disconnecting the hot wire, so running the neutral wire through a switch box was unnecessary. Modern switches including digital timers often require a neutral, making it difficult to use those in older buildings.

Answer (score 1):

One new trend is to power most lighting from a separate circuit from receptacles. That's because circuits containing only lights are unlikely to blow a breaker, especially in the LED age where the whole house might have 5A of lighting.

Now close your eyes and imagine the behind-wall spaces in your house, including above ceilings.  You are trying to run a circuit from light to light to light.  What is easier? Hopping from switch to switch, dodging doorways and windows?  Or hopping from fixture to fixture, remaining in the plane of the ceiling the whole time?

There's also a cubic inch issue.  Going to the switch means 3 cables (supply, onward, lamp) so 6 conductors, 1 for grounds, 1 for cable clamps, 2 for the yoke totalling 10 wires.  On #14 wire that is 20 cubic inches and on #12 it is 22.5.  That's out of the question for a metal 1-gang box, and really pushing it for the deep plastic boxes.

Going to the lamp takes 1 more wire (for switch loop neutral), so 22 or 24.75 c.i., but you're going into a 4" octagon box which is much larger.

The other thing is, this is the classic smart-switch blunder.  When changing from an unpowered switch to one *that obviously needs power* and whose power source is a mystery, **that device needs neutral** since powering via leakage through an incandescent bulb is as dead as incandescent bulbs.    It's vital to check the switch box first and assure that neutral is present.

Also I'm not sure why someone would want such a device, since it is a 24x7 vampire load.